# How can you set the fit tolerance in `NonlinearModelFit`?

Tags: fitting

In `NonlinearModelFit` how can you set the tolerances of where the fitting terminates. I know you can set `MaxIterations` but how can how set the tolerances of parameters in a similar way to Matlab as indicated [here](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/setting-options.html#bt00l89-1)

Comment: I would certainly like to see more details in the documentation about this.  The very compact statement in the documentation on `PrecisionGoal` is "With PrecisionGoal->p and AccuracyGoal->a, the Wolfram Language attempts to make the numerical error in a result of size x be less than 10^-a+|x| 10^-p".  Other languages use the terms like "relative tolerance" and "absolute tolerance" but define exactly what those are.

Comment: Is there a way one can use this to set a termination condition? Roughly speaking I'd like to force my fit to try and continue converging on the data.

Comment: Yes.  I'll look for an example that doesn't readily converge.  But in the meantime, either standardizing the response and/or predictor variables (when that doesn't change the model) and scaling things so that the parameters are on approximately the same scale many times gets things to converge without having to change the termination conditions.  The usual "Please supply a minimal working (or non-working in this case) example" advice would help.